# Convert NSString to a Time, and then calculate "Time Until"

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have been on SO for awhile now trying to get this problem solved but have not had any luck.

In a nutshell I want to take a string like this: `"2011-11-21 11:20:00"` and calculate the `"Time Until".`
In a format like `"1 day 36 mins"` which would be a string I could display in a label.

I cant wrap my head around this. Anyone have some sample code from doing this before? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should help you out.

```
    NSDate * date;

    //Assume dateString is populated and of format NSString * dateString =@"2011-11-21 11:20:00";
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    //EDITED date formatter to correct behavior
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    if (dateString != nil)  {
        date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    }
    [dateFormatter release];

    NSTimeInterval difference = [date timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];
    int days = difference/(3600*24);
    difference -= (float) (days*3600*24);
    int hours = difference/(3600);
    difference -= (float) (hours*3600);
    int minutes = difference/(60);

    NSString * timeRemaining = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dd %dh %dm", days, hours, minutes];
```

Comment: Maudicus, thanks for the reply. I tried the code you offered with the assumed string you said. I am getting this in my log: "-294d -11h -36m" ... im trying to figure out the problem it should only be about 10 days give or take.

Comment: Maudicus, could you tell me how to compensate for the timeZone? Right now its about 6 hours off. I cant seem to get it right. I dont know what these timeStamps have to be so difficult!

Answer (score 3):

@Maudicus is on the right track but has some flaws in his answer.

1. The date format you'd need to use is `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`
2. Once you have the date, you should use [`-[NSCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001451-BBCEGJCC) to figure out the differences between one date and another.  For example:

   ```
   NSDate *date = ...; // the date converted using the date formatter
   NSDate *target = [NSDate date]; // now
   NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
   NSUInteger components = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
   NSDateComponents *difference = [calendar components:components fromDate:date toDate:target options:0];

   NSLog(@"difference: %d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds", [difference days], [difference hours], [difference minutes], [difference seconds]);
   ```

Comment: thank you I edited Maudicus time format and his answer worked. Thanks for the heads up. +1 for the assist!

Answer (score 1):

```
duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (int)audioPlayer.duration / 3600, (int)audioPlayer.duration % 60, nil];
```